# Query repeated property starts with

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Say I have a movie database where you can search by title.

I have a `Movie` model that looks like the following (simplified)

```
class Movie(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    queryName = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: [w.lower() for w in self.name.split()], repeated=True)

    @staticmethod
    def parent_key():
        return ndb.Key(Movie, 'parent')
```

The `queryName` is just a lower case list of the words in `Movie.name`. The `parent_key()` is just for the query basically

If I was searching for the movie Forest Gump, I would want it to show up for the following search terms (and more, these are just examples)

1. 'fo' - 'forest' starts with 'fo'
2. 'gu' - 'gump' starts with 'gu'
3. 'gu fo' - 'forest' starts with 'fo' and 'gump' starts with 'gu'

I can get the first two easily with a query similar to the following

```
movies = Movie\
    .query(ancestor=Movie.parent_key())\
    .filter(Movie.queryName >= x)\
    .filter(Movie.queryName < x + u'\ufffd')\
    .feth(10)
```

where x is 'fo' or 'gu'. Again, this is simply a query that works not my actual code. That comes later. If I expand a bit on the above query to look for two words I thought I could do something like the following however, it doesn't work.

```
movies = Movie\
    .query(ancestor=Movie.parent_key())\
    .filter(Movie.queryName >= 'fo')\
    .filter(Movie.queryName < 'fo' + u'\ufffd')\
    .filter(Movie.queryName >= 'gu')\
    .filter(Movie.queryName < 'gu' + u'\ufffd')\
    .feth(10)
```

Now , this doesn't work because it is looking in `queryName` to see if it has any item which starts with 'fo' and starts with 'gu'. Since that could never be true for a single item in the list, the query returns nothing.

The question is how do you query for `Movies` which have a `queryName` with an item that starts with 'fo' **AND** an item that starts with 'gu'?

Actual Code:

```
class MovieSearchHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        q = self.request.get('q')

        if q:
            q = q.replace('&', '&amp;').lower()
            filters = self.create_filter(*q.split())

            if filters:
                movies = Movie\
                    .query(ancestor=Movie.parent_key())\
                    .filter(*filters)\
                    .fetch(10)

                return self.write_json([{'id': m.movieId, 'name': m.name} for m in movies])

        return self.write_json([])

    def create_filter(self, *args):
        filters = []

        if args:
            for prefix in args:
                filters.append(Movie.queryName >= prefix)
                filters.append(Movie.queryName < prefix + u'\ufffd')

        return filters
```

**Update:**

My current solution is

```
class MovieSearchHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        q = self.request.get('q')

        if q:
            q = q.replace('&', '&amp;').lower().split()
            movieFilter, reducable = self.create_filter(*q)

            if movieFilter:
                movies = Movie\
                    .query(ancestor=Movie.parent_key())\
                    .filter(movieFilter)\
                    .fetch(None if reducable else 10)

                if reducable:
                    movies = self.reduce(movies, q)

                return self.write_json([{'id': m.movieId, 'name': m.name} for m in movies])

        return self.write_json([])

    def create_filter(self, *args):
        if args:
            if len(args) == 1:
                prefix = args[0]
                return ndb.AND(Movie.queryName >= prefix, Movie.queryName < prefix + u'\ufffd'), False

            ands = [ndb.AND(Movie.queryName >= prefix, Movie.queryName < prefix + u'\ufffd')
                    for prefix in args]

            return ndb.OR(*ands), True

        return None, False

    def reduce(self, movies, terms):
        reducedMovies = []

        for m in movies:
            if len(reducedMovies) >= 10:
                return reducedMovies
            if all(any(n.startswith(t) for n in m.queryName) for t in terms):
                reducedMovies.append(m)

        return reducedMovies
```

Still looking for something better though

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using full text search for this, or whoosh, I don't think you will get what you want with straight datastore.

Comment: Yeah I was going to mention that it could be done easily with full text search but my question was already getting too long.  I didn't want to settle for that however because I feel it really impairs usability. Thanks though.